# Dubrovnik, Croatia to Kotor, Montenegro on a Sunday

Tags: car-rentals, insurance, croatia, montenegro

We are looking to travel to Kotor from Dubrovnik on 27th September (a Sunday). We won't be in Dubrovnik until noon, so we will miss the regular bus to Kotor (the last one seems to be at 11am on that day). When we looked to hire a car, we noticed you have to pay a border crossing fee and, more importantly, the car is *not* insured while in Montenegro, which is worrying.

Can anyone recommend car rental companies in Dubrovnik that include insurance, or any alternative methods to get to Kotor (e.g., is there a boat)?

Comment: While researching this more, we've found out about something called a "Green Card", and its availability at the border, for insurance. However, very few *actual* details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, [there is a bus](http://libertasdubrovnik.com/wp-content/uploads/voznired2.pdf) which goes to Kotor at 19:00 (I got that from the website of Dubrovnik's bus station).

I've found also posts (in Spanish) of people recommending to take the ferry between Kamenari and Lepetani to cross the bay, but you would have to get there from Dubrovnik, I don't know if there is any bus connecting Dubrovnik and Kamenari. [This is the ferry website](http://www.ferry.co.me/EN/Index.html)

Also take a look at [this](http://www.croatiatraveller.com/southern_dalmatia/Dubrovnik/Dubrovnik-Montenegro.html) to check the different possibilities that you have to get there.

Comment: Thanks :) Didn't realise there was a regular local bus service to Kotor, as well as the coaches.